# Combine checkbox and paragraph in Google Forms

Tags: google-drive, google-forms

I am trying to create a new survey. The question will be directed to the patients about their current pharmacological therapy. I prepared a checkbox list of medications, but I can't add a textbox beside each check box. My question is whether it would be possible to combine checkbox and paragraph options of Google Forms in one question?